# How to sort Ruby Array of Hashes based on multiple keys and multiple directions?

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array of hashs based on multiple keys and multiple directions (ASC and DESC).

Assume the array looks like:

```
items = [ {field1: '1', field2: 5, field3: 5}, 
          {field1: '1', field2: 1, field3: 3}, 
          {field1: '3', field2: 3, field3: 2},
          {field1: '3', field2: 1, field3: 8}, 
          {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 6}, 
          {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 1} ]
```

I want to create **multiple_sort(items,options)** method which works like:

```
multiple_sort(items, [{field: 'feed1', dir: 'asc'}, {field: 'feed3', dir: 'asc'}])
```

Will generate:

```
        [ {field1: '1', field2: 1, field3: 3},
          {field1: '1', field2: 5, field3: 5}, 
          {field1: '3', field2: 3, field3: 2},
          {field1: '3', field2: 1, field3: 8}, 
          {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 1}, 
          {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 6} ]
```

And

```
multiple_sort(items, [{field: 'feed1', dir: 'asc'}, {field: 'feed3', dir: 'desc'}])
```

Will output:

```
[ {field1: '1', field2: 5, field3: 5},
      {field1: '1', field2: 1, field3: 3}
      {field1: '3', field2: 1, field3: 8},
      {field1: '3', field2: 3, field3: 2}, 
      {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 6}, 
      {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 1} ]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the liberty of interpreting `feed1` as `field1`, and changing the strings to symbols for efficiency.

```
def multiple_sort(array, criteria)
  array.sort do |a, b|
    cmp = 0
    criteria.each do |criterion|
      cmp = a[criterion[:field]] <=> b[criterion[:field]]
      cmp = -cmp if criterion[:dir] == :desc
      break if cmp != 0
    end
    cmp
  end
end


require 'pp'

pp multiple_sort(items, [
  {field: :field1, dir: :asc},
  {field: :field3, dir: :asc}
])
# [{:field1=>"1", :field2=>1, :field3=>3},
#  {:field1=>"1", :field2=>5, :field3=>5},
#  {:field1=>"3", :field2=>3, :field3=>2},
#  {:field1=>"3", :field2=>1, :field3=>8},
#  {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>1},
#  {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>6}]

pp multiple_sort(items, [
  {field: :field1, dir: :asc},
  {field: :field3, dir: :desc}
])
# [{:field1=>"1", :field2=>5, :field3=>5},
#  {:field1=>"1", :field2=>1, :field3=>3},
#  {:field1=>"3", :field2=>1, :field3=>8},
#  {:field1=>"3", :field2=>3, :field3=>2},
#  {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>6},
#  {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

**Code**

```
def multiple_sort(items, options)
  items.sort_by { |h| options.map { |g|
    ((g[:dir]=='asc') ? 1 : -1) * h[g[:field].to_sym].to_i } }
end
```

**Examples**

```
items = [ {field1: '1', field2: 5, field3: 5}, 
          {field1: '1', field2: 1, field3: 3}, 
          {field1: '3', field2: 3, field3: 2},
          {field1: '3', field2: 1, field3: 8}, 
          {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 6}, 
          {field1: '7', field2: 5, field3: 1} ]

options = [{field: 'field1', dir: 'asc'}, {field: 'field3', dir: 'asc'}]
multiple_sort(items, options)
     #=> [{:field1=>"1", :field2=>1, :field3=>3},
     #    {:field1=>"1", :field2=>5, :field3=>5},
     #    {:field1=>"3", :field2=>3, :field3=>2},
     #    {:field1=>"3", :field2=>1, :field3=>8},
     #    {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>1},
     #    {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>6}]
```

```
options = [{field: 'field1', dir: 'desc'}, {field: 'field3', dir: 'desc'}]
multiple_sort(items, options)
  # => [{:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>6},
  #     {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>1},
  #     {:field1=>"3", :field2=>1, :field3=>8},
  #     {:field1=>"3", :field2=>3, :field3=>2},
  #     {:field1=>"1", :field2=>5, :field3=>5},
  #     {:field1=>"1", :field2=>1, :field3=>3}]
```

```
items << {:field1=>"1", :field2=>6, :field3=>5}
  #=> [{:field1=>"1", :field2=>5, :field3=>5},
  #    {:field1=>"1", :field2=>1, :field3=>3},
  #    {:field1=>"3", :field2=>3, :field3=>2},
  #    {:field1=>"3", :field2=>1, :field3=>8},
  #    {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>6},
  #    {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>1},
  #    {:field1=>"1", :field2=>6, :field3=>5}] 

options = [{field: 'field1', dir: 'asc'}, {field: 'field3', dir: 'desc'},
           {field: 'field2', dir: 'desc'}]
multiple_sort(items, options)
  #=> [{:field1=>"1", :field2=>6, :field3=>5},
  #    {:field1=>"1", :field2=>5, :field3=>5},
  #    {:field1=>"1", :field2=>1, :field3=>3},
  #    {:field1=>"3", :field2=>1, :field3=>8},
  #    {:field1=>"3", :field2=>3, :field3=>2},
  #    {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>6},
  #    {:field1=>"7", :field2=>5, :field3=>1}]
```